# PHP слияние двух массивов

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день всем! есть два массива,один с ссылками,второй с ссылками на фото.

```
  $links = array();
  $imgs = array();
  foreach($html->find('a.intro-text') as $d ){
  $links[] = $d->href;
  }

  foreach($html->find('ul.archive-list img')as $i){
   $imgs [] = $i->src;
  }
```

Как слить данные в один массив так чтобы значение $links[0] было в строке вместе с $imgs[0]?

Спасибо заранее)

Comment: В каком виде хотите получить в итоге? что значит "было в строке вместе " ?

Comment: @Arsen уже нашел ответ

Comment: @Arsen вывод должен был быть таким чтобы первая ссылка в массиве была в строке с фото на эту ссылку.

Тоесть href -- src)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разные части одних сущностей хорошо хранить вместе, но не в строке, а в некоторой структуре(объекте или ассоциативном массиве).

Продемонстрирую на данных из соседнего ответа:

```
 $links = array("Саша","Петя","Ваня");
 $imgs = array("Петров","Иванов","Сидоров");

 $result = array_map(function($link, $img){
   return [ // формат сей структуры обсуждаем.
    'link' => $link,
    'img' => $img,
   ];
   // return "$link $img"; // так было бы в авторском формате
 }, $links, $imgs);

 print_r($result);
```

Вывод:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [link] => Саша
            [img] => Петров
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [link] => Петя
            [img] => Иванов
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [link] => Ваня
            [img] => Сидоров
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Все решилось с помощью цикла `for`)

**Для примера**

```
 $links = array("Саша","Петя","Ваня");
 $imgs = array("Петров","Иванов","Сидоров");
 $arr3 = array();
 $cnt = count($links); //Добавляем функцию count чтобы узнать длину массива

 for($i = 0; $i<$cnt; $i++) {
     $arr3[] = $links[$i].' '.$imgs[$i];
 }

 print_r($arr3);
```

**Вывод**

```
Array
(
  [0] => Саша Петров
  [1] => Петя Иванов
  [2] => Ваня Сидоров
)
```

Comment: @vp_arth 
      $arr1 = array("Саша","Петя","Ваня");
      $arr2 = array("Петров","Иванов","Сидоров");
      $arr3 = array();
 
     echo $arr3[0]// Саша Петров  вывод

Comment: Гораздо лучше, спасибо!